# Calculate commision based on level completeness of a binary tree

Tags: php, recursion, binary-tree

I have 2 tables.

1. Business Plans

[image]

2. Users Binary

[image]

Right now, if you see users_binary, The following hierarchy is being developed.

```
        1
     /    \
    3      4
  /   \   /  \
 19   33 18   32
```

I want to calculate commission based of completeness of level. I has 2 childs. Its first level is complete. Now User 1 is on PLAN 1. Plan 1's right and left points are 20 and commission percentage is 4.5. It's first level is complete. It will get ((20+20)*4.5%) commission. When 3 and 4 also completes their 1st levels, user 1 will get ((20+20+20+20)*4.5%) commission. Just 1 thing to note. In query, we will note that the commission being calculated is from this Monday to Saturday and point_status should be equal to N.

This is my getBasicTree function.

```
function getBasicTree($user_id)
    {
        $query="select user_id,first_name,last_name,leg from users 
                where introducer_id = '".$user_id."'
                and leg != ''";
        if(($data=$this->CustomQuery($query))!=null)
        {
            return $data;   
        }
        return 0;   
    }
```

Anyone willing to help me out understanding the logic how it will be done. I am unable to understand recursion and make a logic for it.

Comment: do you got the answer? It would be great if you can share the final answer here. So, other can use it...